# Is it possible to omit multiplication operator in polish/prefix notation?

Tags: polish-notation

In infix notation, (2/2(3+3)) means (2/(2*(3+3)). The multiplication sign is omitted.

In polish/prefix notation, is it possible to omit multiplication sign? For instance, is it acceptable to write ( * + 2 3 ( / 12 4)) as ( + 2 3 ( / 12 4))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the reasons to have polish notation is to get rid of brackets! Expressions in Polish notation are easy to parse and evaluate.

So, the answer to you question is: No, you cannot get rid of the multiplication by putting in brackets, you are only defeating the purpose of having Polish notation by trying to do that.